# digit decimal picker

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь найти аналог datepicker(bootstrap), только для чисел. Чтобы при нажатии на инпут появлялось окно(типа калькулятора), где можно было бы ввести число,в том числе и вещественное. Может кто видел что-то подобное(гугление пока не дало результат)?

Upd: нашел такой решение [numpad](https://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-numpad.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Первый попавшийся пример](https://www.codeseek.co/paulo-navarro/input-calculator-teCnG) с поиска:

```js
var resultados = new Array();

function calcula() {
  enviaParaEquacao('');
  var val = $("#pbtCalcForm").html().replace(/×/g, "*").replace(/÷/g, "/");
  var resultado = eval(val);
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val(resultado);
  resultados.push(resultado);
  esvazia();
}

function cancela() {
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val('');
}

function esvazia() {
  $("#pbtCalcForm").html('');
}

function cancelaEsvazia() {
  cancela();
  esvazia();
}

function corrigeString(string) {
  var strArr = string.split('');
  var string2 = '';
  var ultimoIndice = strArr.length - 1;
  var apagaPrimeira = ((strArr[0] === '0') && ((strArr[1] !== '.') && (strArr[1] !== undefined))) ? true : false;
  var contaPonto = 0;
  $.each(strArr, function(i, value) {
    if (value === '.') {
      contaPonto++;
    }
    if (((apagaPrimeira === false) || (i !== 0)) &&
      ((value !== '.') || (contaPonto < 2))) {
      string2 += value;
    }
  });
  if (strArr[0] === '.') {
    string2 = '0' + string2;
  }
  return string2;
}

function corrigeString2(string) {
  string = string.replace("×0", "").replace("÷0", "");
  var stringArr = string.split('.');
  if (stringArr[1] !== undefined) {
    var stringReversa = stringArr[1].split("").reverse().join("");
    var stringArr2 = stringReversa.split('');
    var string2 = '';
    $.each(stringArr2, function(i, value) {
      if (value !== '0') {
        string2 = string2 + value;
      }
    });
    if (string2.length > 1) {
      var string2 = string2.split("").reverse().join("");
      return stringArr[0] + '.' + string2;
    } else {
      return stringArr[0];
    }
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}

function insereCaracter(caracter) {
  var value = corrigeString($("#pbtCalcInput").val() + caracter);
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val(value);
}

function enviaParaEquacao(caracter) {
  var equa = $("#pbtCalcForm").html();
  var input = $("#pbtCalcInput").val();
  if (input !== '') {
    $("#pbtCalcForm").html(corrigeString2(equa + input + caracter));
    $("#pbtCalcInput").val(0);
  }
}

function backspace() {
  var sub = $("#pbtCalcInput").val().substring(0, $("#pbtCalcInput").val().length - 1);
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val(sub);
}

function mostraMemoria() {
  var resultados2 = resultados.reverse();
  $.each(resultados2, function(index, data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
      var result = "&nbsp;<span class='itemMemoria'>" + data + "</span>,";
      $("#pbtMemoria").append(result);
    }
  });
  $("#pbtPainel").slideUp("fast");
  $("#pbtMemoria").slideDown("fast");
  //alert(resultados[2]);
}

function fechaMemoria() {
  $("#pbtPainel").slideDown("fast");
  $("#pbtMemoria").slideUp("fast");
}

function enviaMemoria(valor) {
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val(valor);
}

function enviaParaInput(input) {
  $("#" + input).val($("#pbtCalcInput").val()).focus();
  fechaCalculadora();
}

function fechaCalculadora() {
  $("#pbtCalculadora, #pbtCalculadoraBackground").fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}

function corrigeTitle(title) {
  if (title.length >= 20) {
    return title.substring(0, 17) + '...';
  } else {
    return title;
  }
}

function montaCalculadora(id) {
  var titulo = corrigeTitle($("#" + id).attr('title'));
  var tituloTitle = $("#" + id).attr('title'); //DOH!
  var value = $("#" + id).val();
  var html = '<div id="pbtCalculadoraBackground"></div><div id="pbtCalculadora"> <div id="pbtCalcCabecalho"> <h1 title="' + tituloTitle + '">' + titulo + '<span class="cFechaBot" id="pbtFechaCalc"></span></h1><div id="pbtCalcForm"></div><input type="text" id="pbtCalcInput" value="' + value + '" /></div> <div id="pbtMemoria"><h1>Memória<span class="cFechaBot" id="pbtFechaMemoria"></span></h1></div><div id="pbtPainel"><div class="linha"><div class="pbtBotao l1 acao" data-acao="memoria">M</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 acao" data-acao="cancelaEsvazia">CE</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 acao" data-acao="cancela">C</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 acao" data-acao="backspace">&larr;</div></div><div class="linha"><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">7</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">8</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">9</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 operador">&#247;</div></div><div class="linha"><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">4</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">5</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">6</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 operador">&#215;</div></div><div class="linha"><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">1</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">2</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">3</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 operador">-</div></div><div class="linha"> <div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">0</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 numero">.</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 acao" data-acao="calcula">=</div><div class="pbtBotao l1 operador">+</div></div><div class="linha"><div class="pbtBotao l4 acao" data-acao="envia" data-input="' + id + '">ENVIAR<div></div></div></div>';
  $('body').append(html);

  $('#pbtCalcInput').focus().setCursorPosition(2);


}




$("body").delegate(".numero", "click", function() {
  insereCaracter($(this).html());
  $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
});
$("body").delegate(".operador", "click", function() {
  enviaParaEquacao($(this).html());
  $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
});
$("body").delegate(".acao", "click", function() {
  if ($(this).data("acao") !== undefined) {
    switch ($(this).data("acao")) {
      case 'calcula':
        calcula();
        break;
      case 'cancela':
        cancela();
        break;
      case 'cancelaEsvazia':
        cancelaEsvazia();
        break;
      case 'backspace':
        backspace();
        break;
      case 'memoria':
        mostraMemoria();
        break;
      case 'envia':
        enviaParaInput($(this).data('input'));
    }
  }
  $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
});
$("body").delegate("#pbtCalcInput", "keypress", function(e) { // alert(e.which)
  if (!((e.which >= 48) && (e.which <= 57) || (e.which === 46))) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if ((e.which == 13) || (e.which == 61)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calcula();
    $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 43) {
    e.preventDefault();
    enviaParaEquacao('+');
    $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 45) {
    e.preventDefault();
    enviaParaEquacao('-');
    $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 47) {
    e.preventDefault();
    enviaParaEquacao('÷');
    $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 42) {
    e.preventDefault();
    enviaParaEquacao('×');
    $("#pbtCalcInput").focus();
  }

});
$("body").delegate("#pbtCalcInput", "keyup", function(e) {
  $("#pbtCalcInput").val(corrigeString($("#pbtCalcInput").val()));
});
$("body").delegate("#pbtFechaMemoria", "click", function() {
  fechaMemoria();
});
$("body").delegate(".itemMemoria", "click", function() {
  enviaMemoria($(this).html());
  fechaMemoria();
});
$("body").delegate("#pbtFechaCalc, #pbtCalculadoraBackground", "click", function() {
  fechaCalculadora();
});
$(".pbtCalc").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var button = '<div class="pbtCalcBot" data-id="' + id + '"><span>+</span><span>-</span><br><span>×</span><span>=</span></div>';
  $(this).wrap('<div id="pbtC' + id + '" class="pbtContainer"></div>');
  $("#pbtC" + id).append(button);
});
$("body").delegate(".pbtCalcBot", "click", function() {
  montaCalculadora($(this).data("id"));
});


function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  } else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos(input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
```

```css
#pbtCalculadoraBackground {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#pbtCalculadora {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

#pbtCalcCabecalho {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#pbtCalcCabecalho h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000
}

#pbtCalcForm {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#pbtCalcInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

#pbtCalcInput:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#pbtMemoria {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #0b8820;
  overflow: auto;
}

.itemMemoria {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemMemoria:hover {
  color: #0b8820;
}

#pbtMemoria h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 4px;
}

.linha {
  display: block;
}

.pbtBotao {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px none #0b8820;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pbtBotao:hover {
  background-color: #97fb99;
}

.l1 {
  width: 25%;
}

.l4 {
  width: 100%;
}

.numero {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.operador {
  background-color: rgb(226, 249, 224);
}

.acao {
  background-color: rgb(226, 249, 224);
}

.cFechaBot {
  float: right;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  background-color: #700000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cFechaBot:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.cFechaBot::after {
  content: 'x';
}

.pbtContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: none;
}

.pbtCalcBot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 32px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #5DC96F;
  border: 1px solid #0b8820;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pbtCalcBot span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #0b8820;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.pbtCalcBot:hover {
  background-color: #97fb99;
}


/* a partir daqui o css serve apenas para o exemplo */

body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  border-width;
  0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #888;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.pbtInput {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #0b8820;
}

.pbtInput:focus {
  background-color: #dbf9e2;
  outline: none;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Input Calculator</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Input Calculadora</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <label>Valor Juros Líquido</label>
    <input type="text" id="exemplo1" class="pbtCalc pbtInput" title="Valor Juros Líquido " value="99" />
    <label>Valor Total</label>
    <input type="text" id="exemplo2" class="pbtCalc pbtInput" title="Valor Total" value="5" />
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: немного не то, но все равно спасибо. нашел решение на jquery(прикрепил к вопросу)